# On localhost, two different projects share the same session

Tags: php, codeigniter

My localhost is XAMPP. The two projects are basically the same code, at least the login module. The projects are built with Codeigniter.

My problem is, for example, if I logged in on Project A, then I found I'm automatically logged in on Project B, too.

The two projects does not use the same database, but their login code is the same. When the user visit the page, I will check the variable `$this->session->isLoggedIn` first, if so, I will redirect the page to the user page. I do find that they use the same session id. Is this a common issue on the localhost, since they share the same domain, or I made a mistake?

Comment: while set session you need to differentiate the session like this $this->session->set_userdata('project_A_username', 'usernamehere');  and $this->session->set_userdata('project_B_username', 'usernamehere'); . php session is common for all your project . so you have to differentaite like this

Comment: @JYoThI As you said, all my localhost should share the same session if I don't differentiate the session? Do I understand you correctly? If so, this will not happen in the live environment, since they are not under the same domain?

Comment: yes if they are different domain it will not happen .@SSD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while set `session` you need to `differentiate` the `session`  Based on project 
 for your identification like this

`$this->session->set_userdata('project_A_username', 'usernamehere');`

and

`$this->session->set_userdata('project_B_username', 'usernamehere');` .

php session is common for all your project . so you have to differentiate.

OP comments : *If so, this will not happen in the live environment, since they are not under the same domain?*

yes it will not happen .since they are in different domain .

Answer (score 0):

run $ php artisan config:cache on both projects

this usually happens on apache on windows

its explained here https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19454