# Codeigniter session works for all my projects on localhost

Tags: codeigniter

I am sorry to bug you if this question has been answered before. 
Every codeigniter projects on my localhost share the same session until i log out of any of the projects.
How do i rectify this issue?, Thanks

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45003604/3585500).

Answer (score 1):

Change the session cookie name in config file default is `ci_session`.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session#session-preferences

Comment: Thanks very much, this was helpful, and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give separate sessions for seperate projects like this

```
$this->session->set_userdata('project_One_user', 'userdetailsvalue');
```

and

```
$this->session->set_userdata('project_Two_user', 'userdetailsvalue');
```